# Weird driver behavior on frame change

Tags: drivers

I came across some weird driver behavior and hope someone can explain this to me.

I was trying to create a wheel that rotates automatically on the floor when it is moved along. (Just like real world wheels do.)

To achieve this, I wanted to use a driver. (Use position to calculate rotation -> rotate the wheel)
However, I got different results for the *same* frame while scrubbing on the timeline:

[image: Weird drivers]

Note that I'm always on frame 44 and the xLocation is also equal. But the driver result varies and the wheel's rotation vary.

I found the difference to be dependent on whether I scrub using the mouse or the keyboard, and also from which direction I reach the frame.
(44 is arbitrary - it's the same for any other frame)

This is the Driver:
[image: Driver]

*(not the solution, yet ;) )*

Pressing "update dependencies" seems to fix it, but it is very impractical in this situation, because I'm trying to see if the wheel slips on the floor, and I need to jump quickly back and forth between frames and can't press the button each time.

Thinking this has sth. to do with the Dependency Graph, I tried to open this file in 2.8 and got the same result. Also in 2.79b and 2.79.5.

I would expect to get consistent values on the same frame. Any ideas why this happens? Thanks!!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the just the dependencies graph not updating in the right time just as you speculated. The value `101°` is actually the result of the driver at frame `45` while the value `96.2°` is actually the result of the driver at frame `43`. The true value of the driver at frame `44` is `98.5°`.

When you approach the frame `44` from the left, the last computed value is at frame `45`, so its value is used. When you approach the frame `44` from the right, the last computed value is at frame `43`, so its value is used. If you updated the dependencies at the frame `44`, the true value is used.

I don't think there is an easy way to solve this, and this is one of many reasons I stopped using drivers. I recommend using Animation Nodes instead.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm just wondering why a frame change wouldn't automatically trigger a dependency update?

Comment: @michaelh Honestly, I don't know, drivers are unpredictable. However, I think the reason is as follows. When you change the frame from `45` to `44`, blender recognizes a change and execute the driver to update, however, blender recognize the change when you are still at frame `45`, subsequently it executes the driver when it is at frame `45` and not the target frame `44`.